# Curly brace uniform initilaization not recognised in Eclipse in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, initialization

I am learning C++ and I am using Eclipse as an IDE. I downloaded the latest version for Mac (Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)). I am trying uniform initialization but Eclipse gives me an error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int x{ 5 }; 
   std::cout << x; 
   return 0;
}
```

If I type instead:

```
    int x(5);
```

or

```
    int x=5;
```

It works!
The error shown is the following:

Building file: ../src/HelloWorld2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld2.d" -MT"src/HelloWorld2.o" -o "src/HelloWorld2.o" "../src/HelloWorld2.cpp"
../src/HelloWorld2.cpp:5:10: error: expected ';' at end of declaration

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the compiler is set to compiler for C++11 or higher. By default, it might be  an earlier version.

Comment: Eclipse is a very crappy C++ IDE.

Comment: Haha, any suggestions for a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find how to make Eclipse compatible for C++11, but then I found a website (took a while). Here is the solution.

- On the project explorer window, right-click your project and choose properties at the bottom of the menu.
- Go to "C/C++ Build" on the left, expand the options by clicking the small arrow and then select 'settings'
- On the right side of the window, there is a list of settings. Select the 'Miscellaneous' one.
- There will be a field called 'Other flags' to the right of that list. Add the following (put a space at the end of the current text).

  "-std=c++0x"

That's it!

Comment: The last few years of Eclipse releases have also had a *Dialect* option on the *Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings* *Tool Settings* tab under *GCC C++ Compiler* and *GCC C Compiler* options.